# Why ZipInputStream doesn't find files in it

Tags: java

I want to read data in files into a Zip file in Java

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file.zip");
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
ZipEntry entry;
while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(zis);
}
```

But when I arrive to line:

```
while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
```

It doesn't go into while loop
why can't access to files in it, and zis doesn't has and entry in itself?

Comment: Make sure your file.zip is in the correct path. Otherwise check the file permission (if you use linux)

Comment: Any errors? Does file.zip exist? Does it actually have any zip entries in it?

Comment: yes, my zip file exist in correct path. i am in window. it has 1 ,csv file in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error!
the position of file is important for java
i change the position of file to out of my project , and it get correct
thanks all